# How to query MySQL table for a sample with date column where each month has equal weight?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores comments people made on a bulletin board and the date the comment was made, for example..

```
  Id|text                                 |date_created
  1|'Yankees over Sox in AL East'         |03-31-2017
  2|'these pretzels making me thirsty'    |05-12-2017
  3|'Go ahead punk, make my day'          |06-11-2017
  4|'I love Selena Gomez'                 |07-28-2017
  5|'I thought I saw a ghost'             |10-31-2017
```

*Imagine the table has many more comments and a greater distribution in date than this sample.*

Supposing we want to get a sample of 1000 random comments but we want each month to have equal weight in the sample (each month in the sample will have an equal number of comments).

I got the first part of this down with the below...

```
select text,date_created from item_comment order by rand() limit 1000
```

Any thoughts on how to get the second?

date_created is type datetime.

Comment: You mean that we need to have same amount of rows from each month in the sample ?

Comment: Yes, same number of rows from each month.

Comment: What is the data type of `date_created`?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the comments come from different years?  We're only interested in months?

Comment: And does every comment really have the same id. How confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) = 12 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) = 11 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all 
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) = 10 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  9 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all 
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  8 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  7 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all 
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  6 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  5 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all 
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  4 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  3 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all 
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  2 order by rand() limit 1000 
union all
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) =  1 order by rand() limit 1000
```

Comment: The OP does not want 1000 comments per month. They want up to 1000 comments, with an equal number of comments per month. Of course this is mathematically impossible to attain precisely!

Comment: This might not be the cleanest solution but it gives me some direction.

Comment: Agreed on not the cleanest, but it works and it is easy for others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can enumerate the rows by month and then choose a particular number:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@ym = concat(year(date_created), month(month_created)), @rn + 1,
                        if(@ym := concat(year(date_created), month(month_created)), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @ym := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by year(date_created), month(month_created)
     ) t
where rn <= 1000 / 12;
```

The "1000 / 12" assumes there are 12 months -- an arbitrary assumption.  You can choose the same number of rows for all months, by adjusting the value.

Comment: Your answer is confusing as hell.

Comment: This is the most performing way of dong what you want.  If you weren't rude, I might include some explanation.  If you understood how variables work in MySQL, it would not be confusing at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MONTH function to select the number of comments per month

```
select text,date_created from item_comment where MONTH( date_created ) = 12 order by rand() limit 1000
```

The above script will get 100o random comments from December

Comment: This will only get the comments for a given month, but I want to get the sample to cover all months.

Comment: If you use this poster idea, then repeat the logic 12 times for each of the months then union all the results together.  You should get what you seek.